# Join multiple tables - Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have four tables to query using Nhibernate - QueryOver.

Classes :

```
class Process {
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;} 
}

class Task {
int Id {get;set;}
int Name {get;set;}
IList<Process> Process { get; set; }
}


class ScheduledTask {
int Id {get;set;}
int Name {get;set;}
DateTime From { get; set; }
DateTime To { get; set; }
Task Task { get; set; }
}


class ArchivedTask {
int Id {get;set;}
int Name {get;set;}
Task Task { get; set; }
}
```

I tried the following query but didn't work. I'm still working on it but with no clue how to create a query with multiple joins like this. I prefer to use QueryOver or criteria instead of createQuery

```
 Process p = null;
 Task t = null;
 ScheduledTask st = null;
 ArchivedTask at = null;

 var task = session.QueryOver<Task>(() => t)
       .JoinAlias(() => t.Process , () => p)
       .JoinAlias(() => st.Task, () => t)
       .JoinAlias(() => at.Task, () => t)
       .JoinAlias(() => WRAlias.WorkOrders, () => WOAlias)
       .JoinAlias(() => WOAlias.Locations, () => locationAlias)
       .JoinEntityAlias(() => AspAlias, () => AspAlias.Id == WRAlias.CreatedBy)
       .Where(x => t.Process.Id == 1)
       .TransformUsing(Transformers.AliasToBean<Task>()).List<Task>();
```

I want to return to me a json look like this :

```
  {
       "Task":{
          "Name":"task1",
          "Processes":[
             {
                "Id":1,
                "Name":"P1"
             },
             {
                "Id":2,
                "Name":"P2"
             }
          ],
          "ScheduledTask":{
             "Name":"scheduled task",
             "From":"12/12/2012",
             "To":"13/12/2012"
          },
          "ArchivedTask"{
             "Id":1,
             "Name":"archived task"
          }
       }
    }
}
```

I need a way to create the above Json using nhibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to your `Task` class same thing as you did with `Process`:

```
class Task 
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    int Name {get;set;}
    IList<Process> Processes{ get; set; }
    IList<ScheduledTask> ScheduledTask{ get; set; }
    IList<ArchivedTask> ArchivedTask{ get; set; }
}
```